# jQuery rotating through list items in a gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, html-lists

This has probably been answered before and I already know how this should work, but for some reason it is not. I think it may be how I am looping through the elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var element = '#gallery ul#gallery-container';
 var idx=0;
 var timeout = 3000;
 var number =  $(element + ' li').length;

function changeSlide() {

    $(element + ' li:eq(' + idx + ')').fadeOut();

    idx = idx + 1;

    if (idx == number) {
        idx=0;
    }

    $(element + ' li:eq(' + idx + ')').fadeIn().delay(timeout).delay(0,   function() {
        changeSlide();
    });;

}

 $(element + ' li').hide();

 $(element + ' li:first').fadeIn().delay(timeout).delay(0, function() {
    changeSlide();
 });
});
```

Then the list is like this:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul id="gallery-container">
        <li><img src="media/images/screen-shot-02.jpg" width="173" height="258" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="media/images/screen-shot-01.jpg" width="173" height="258" alt=" "></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

I was trying to get it to loop through the elements one by one, after a delay so the list item calls the function and hides itself, then the counter is incremented and then the current index is shown.
I suspect the culprit to be this as if I put an alert in the function it is called:

```
 $(element + ' li:eq(' + idx + ')').fadeOut();
```

Comment: According to this http://api.jquery.com/delay/ the `delay()` function does not have a callback function, so `changeSlide()` never gets executed I'm thinking.

Comment: For some reason, changeSlide() is called the first time, but when it gets to the function the $(element + ' li:eq(' + idx + ')').fadeOut(); isn't called. I may have to resort to setTimeout and work with that!

Comment: Yeah, and note the double `;;` in `changeSlide()`'s last line, that's stopping your script.

Comment: Completely missed that! and Also didn't realise that was the case. I just assumed that things like that would be skipped over as it was just an empty line. I assumed wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is, as the comment states, `delay` does not do what you think it does - you should be looking at the native `setTimeout` function instead. In addition to that, there are multiple places where this could be made more efficient. Have a look at this:

```
var element = $('#gallery-container li'),
    length = element.length,
    current = 0,
    timeout = 3000;

function changeSlide() {
    element.eq(current++).fadeOut(300, function(){
        if(current === length){
            current = 0;
        }

        element.eq(current).fadeIn(300);
    });

    setTimeout(changeSlide, timeout);
}

element.slice(1).hide();
setTimeout(changeSlide, timeout);
```

We try not to evoke the jQuery function with a dynamically generated selector, but instead manipulate a single instance of a jQuery object containing all the slides cached at the start. We also use the callback function provided by the `fade` functions to fade in the next slide after the current one has faded out.

See http://www.jsfiddle.net/b3Lf5/1/ for a simple demo

Comment: Bingo! That has worked a treat, and yeah that is way more efficient. You are a legend. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would do it something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = '#gallery ul#gallery-container';
    var idx = 0;
    var timeout = 3000;
    var number = $(element + ' li').length;

    setInterval(function () {
        idx = (idx + 1) % number;
        $(element + ' li:visible').fadeOut();
        $(element + ' li:eq(' + idx + ')').fadeIn();
    },timeout);
    $(element + ' li:not(:first)').hide();
});
```

Or better still, wrap it in a plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.customGallery = function (options) {
        defaults = {
            timeout : 3000
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var idx = 0, number = $(this).children('li').size(), element = this;
            setInterval(function () {
                idx = (idx + 1) % number;
                $(element).children('li:visible').fadeOut();
                $(element).children('li:eq(' + idx + ')').fadeIn();
            },options.timeout);
            $(element).children('li:not(:first)').hide();
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#gallery-container').customGallery()
});
```

**edit:** Edited the plugin code to bring it into line with good practice.

Comment: The plugin idea is excellent. I will implement that as soon as I rewrite the code later.

Comment: I tend to wrap any jQuery code which I might want to reuse in future in a plugin. It just makes it so easy to extend and use for something else. I have a huge wealth of plugins which I've built up over time.

Comment: Oh and BTW JavaScript's `setInterval` will repeat an action every x milliseconds, which eliminates the need for your function recursively calling itself.